# Programmatically interact with attached iOS/iPods in OSX 10.6

Tags: iphone, macos, itunes, ipod

I am trying to develop a simple menu bar application that would let me visualize the charging status of my attached iPhone/iPad without having to launch iTunes. After a long search, I am unable to conclude if this is a possibility with the Snow Leopard APIs.

My search has led me to a service running at boot time called com.apple.ipodserver, but I am unable to find any public API surrounding it.

Is my idea implementable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several utilities for iphone on MAC and Windows , but most of them interact with the file system of your iphone .. i guess you would have to write one app which will run on your iphone and provide interface to your app on mac and your app on mac will use data from that interface ...
e.g. your app on iphone can create a txt file and update battery charging status in it and your app on mac can read that file so far so simple

Comment: ..and of coarse nothing is impossible ;)

Comment: That sounds like a wonderful idea. I could have the app run in the background for the duration of the docking. I guess it would be good to also have a mechanism to launch the app as soon as the device is placed on the dock or connected to my Mac. Thanks! I am going to fish for other ideas before marking this as the answer :)

Comment: yeah sure me too interested in other creative ideas :)

Comment: Already started working on this idea. Not perfect (at least not until some private/public API is discovered that would enable interacting with iOS devices). Thanks for it!

Comment: were you able to access the root of the iphone file system

Comment: hey [look](http://www.redmondpie.com/iphone-attack-reveals-passwords-in-6-minutes-video/) what they ve done  _making use of the existing exploits that provide access to large parts of the iOS file system even for the locked device_

Comment: I am not accessing the iPhone file system. So far I am just using public APIs to get whatever information I can get.