# How do you get the charge status of a connected iPhone from the Mac?

Tags: iphone, macos, itunes, command-line-interface

In iTunes, you can see the charge status of the iPhone currently connected:

[image: Screenshot of iTunes showing an iPhone in the list of devices with the charge status indicated.]

This updates as the phone charges, and even shows when the phone is done charging.

Is there a way I can discover the charge status programmatically from the Mac? Any programming language or API is fine.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that it wasn't *entirely* clear that I wanted to access this from the Mac - not from the iPhone. Edited…

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041263

Comment: Yes, that's definitely along the same lines - I'm open to suggestions of moderation if needed.

Comment: This must be possible as Linux does it, when you plug an iPhone (or other mobile) in you get the charge level of the phone displayed. I'd post an image but I don't have enough 'reputation points'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the *only official* way to communicate with the iPhone over USB/Bluetooth is by signing up to the "Made for iPhone" program:

http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

Unfortunately the documentation seems to be closed to registered members so I can't find out if the API for this is public or private.  You could contact Apple to check before applying.

UPDATE : As mentioned, this might not work for Mac/PC <-> iPhone communication over USB.  There are several apps that do things with the phone over USB (although usually for reading/writing files).  I'd start by looking at the source code of those:

http://code.google.com/p/iphonedisk

This should put you at least in a position where you have a connection to the device and are able to send/receive commands.  Everyone who's ever done this sort of thing has had to spend time reverse engineering the thing :)  The jailbreak community might be able to provide some insight too, although having to actually jailbreak the device is probably unacceptable.

Comment: i think this is only for accessories, and wont grant access from the mac side unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, I've never looked into it as never had to do it.  I guess I'd start by looking at the source code of other apps that talk to the iPhone over USB, such as the FUSE extension: http://code.google.com/p/iphonedisk/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fmobilefs.  While it won't provide the code you need, it's a step in the right direction just figuring out how to "speak" with the phone.

Comment: I'm not sure if the iPhoneDisk code will be helpful or not, but it's at least the direction I was thinking in; the Bonjour app running on the iPhone isn't a bad idea, but isn't particularly useful for my purposes. Thanks for the link!

Comment: No problem.  Just browsing iphone-dev.org (jailbreak guys), they actually have a page on how the USB communication works: http://wikee.iphwn.org/usb:usbmux

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend setting up a bonjour service in an App on the iOS device to communicate with the computer. The app will then communicate the changes in the batter status using the batteryMonitoringEnabled property of UIDevice. Take a look at the samples code here.

[BatteryStatus Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BatteryStatus/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008812)

And here is the class reference

[UIDevice Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)

And finally Bonjour programming

[Bonjour programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/PublishingServices.html)

Comment: That would definitely work, but that's not quite useful for what I ultimately have in mind (it would be inconvenient to force the user to run the app all the time). Thanks for the suggestion, though!